# Snowflake - insert date

Tags: sql, date, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a value of `12/31/18` and created table in snowflake:

```
create table my_date (a date);

insert into my_date values ('12/31/18');

select * from my_date;
```

Result: `0018-12-31`

I want to get: `2018-12-31`

I saw about 2 number format:
https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/parameters.html#label-two-digit-century-start

but not sure if this is specification of a column type or data needs to be transformed before the insert?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parameter `two_digit_century_start` seems not to be used when parameter `date_input_format` is set to `AUTO`. You can get your example working correctly by setting the date format with a parameter ("alter session..." statement on line 2 below). Your complete working example would look like this:

```
create table my_date (a date);
alter session set DATE_INPUT_FORMAT = 'MM/DD/YY';
insert into my_date values ('12/31/18');
select * from my_date;
```

This results in `2018-12-31`.

Snowflake best-practices recommend to specify the format explicitly with `to_date(value, 'format')` or by setting the format in parameters. You can find the best practices for date/time functions from Snowflake documentation here: https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/date-time-input-output.html#date-time-function-format-best-practices

Comment: Got it: `insert into my_date values (to_date('12/31/18', 'MM/DD/YY'));`